# Equal a fixed reference

Tags: reference, google-sheets, offset

I wish to create a fixed reference text that will not change dynamically. The reference should not change when I add an extra row, as it usually does. Say, a cell `A1` has this content:

```
=E5
```

and thus takes the value of cell `E5`. If I add a new row so the referenced cell is `E6`, the value of my cell `A1` also changes to:

```
=E6
```

Is it possible to type in a reference to a cell that will never change dynamically but will remain `E5` e.g. no matter how I do cell rearranging?

*I namely have a sheet of posts whereto I often add new rows. The topmost post should always be shown in another cell.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you describe I think:

```
=offset(A1,5,4)
```

would serve (though the more usual requirement is probably "the other way around" - ie keep a cell referenced to a value whose location may change, such as a totals row when further data is added).

[offset](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379)